# No Java Virtual machine was found error in Eclipse HELIOS\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, helios

Got the below Error messages when i try to open the Eclipse.
***"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java Virtual machine was found after searching the follwing locations:
C:\ECLIPSE\HELIOS\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH"***

i have modified the eclipse.ini (C:\ECLIPSE\HELIOS) by adding the below lines,

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

After that change, i'm able to access the Eclipse. but most of my colleague and web suggested the below different options.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

and

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\javaw.exe
```

Please help me with this.
which one is correct option for this error.?

Comment: You want the Java 7 JRE. jdk1.5.0 is very old and is obsolete.

Comment: Yes. want JRE 7 and JDK 1.5.0 versions. Project team don't wanted to upgrade the JDK version due to some restrictions.

Comment: did u try setting it up through server configuration like windows->preference->tomcat 7->intalled jre

Comment: i haven't tried that yet. please give me detailed steps to do that and why is it required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your eclipse.ini file make sure you are pointing -vm to your jdk installation.You have already did but refer below for more detail [Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value%3A_Windows_Example)

Comment: Thanks for info. 
In my error message, it shows **No Java Virtual machine in jre\bin\javaw.exe**. but in the link that you have shared earlier points to `jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe`. 

Is it require only javaw.exe` file.? or whole JRE and JDK package to work Eclipse.?

i have tried using both the below ways. both of them gives the successful Eclipse launch.
`-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`
&
`-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: I just wanted to know, whether it gives any error in my application later due to this.

And also how to avoid this kind of errors in future when installing eclipse in other Pc's.

Comment: Yes, it requires whole JRE and JDK package. Few steps are enough to avoid this issue as far as I understand your problem correctly 1. Install you JRE and JDK 2. Add your JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME to install directories 3. Make sure you are referring installed package by navigating to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE and select your JRE package.

Comment: 4. For JDK,see the one Eclipse is running under, go to Help->About Eclipse Platform->Configuration Details, and look for the property eclipse.vm. and make sure you are pointing to your installed JDK package